# Setup a database before using Laravel Backpack?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-backpack

The Laravel Backpack docs seem to assume that users already have a working database from which to query data. Is this assumption accurate, or is there in fact a certain way of building the database using the Backpack resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's expected that you have a database server running somewhere and that you have configured your laravel application to point to that database.

If you look in `config/database.php`, you'd configure one or more server in the `connections` array. See the [oficial Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database) for more details.

Backpack for Laravel, packages it pulls in, and laravel itself offer some "generators" that can be used to help you in your development by creating stubbed out [Migration files](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations) which are used to add, edit, or remove tables from your configured database and [Eloquent Database Modles](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent) which are used by your application to interact with those tables.

You don't nessicarily have to have a connected database to generate these files and work on filling in the stubs with details relevant to your application. However, before you can run `php artisan migrate` to apply the migrations or start actually using the Models to query or store data, you will need to configure that connection to a running database server.

The database server could be one running on your local or remote machine that you set up yourself, something provided by a service like AWS, or even in a virtualized environment like the one provided automatically when using the official [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead)

With your being new to laravel, Backpack, and maybe php development in general I would highly recommend using Laravel Homestead to develop your application. It's incredibly simple to use and ensures that everything you need to get started is available.

Answer (score 0):

The third video in their tutorial uses Blueprint to generate models and relationships, seemingly instead of using Eloquent.

https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/getting-started-videos

Comment: Just a note, if you need to add more detail to a question, you can edit the question and add it to the body. Adding additional details as answers is frowned upon and generally results in down votes.